# Linux regex for .json file

Tags: json, regex, linux, shell, scripting

I have a .json file containing the following parameters:

```
{
  "account_ref" : "dh2fk3weh28dnd",
  "fname" : "john",
  "sname" : "smith",
  "address" : "42 test street",
  "product" : "all",
  "email" : "j.smith@aol.com",
  "tele" : "0384756783"
}
```

This file will be on a linux server and I need find a way to extract the account_ref value and insert it into a csv file using automation.

I have no experience in this scripting, regex and I believe that regex may be the answer to extracting the account_ref value. Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to work with a lot of JSON in your linux CLI or scripts, I've heard [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the best tool for that. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

";" is csv delimiter

qa.json is file with you data

output.csv is result csv

> $ cat qa.json
>
> { "account_ref" : "dh2fk3weh28dnd", "fname" : "john", "sname" :
>   "smith", "address" : "42 test street", "product" : "all", "email" :
>   "j.smith@aol.com", "tele" : "0384756783", }

```
$ cat qa.json | awk -F'\"' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ((i%2)==0) { if($i=="account_ref"){ print $i ";" $(i+2)}}}}' > output.csv
```

or

```
awk -F'\"' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ((i%2)==0) { if($i=="account_ref"){ print $i ";" $(i+2)}}}}' qa.json  > output.csv
```

> $ cat output.csv
>
> account_ref;dh2fk3weh28dnd

Comment: how about `sed -r -n 's/.*(account_ref).*:.*"(.*)".*/\1;\2/p' qa.json` ?